# Update MKPF text during save in MB1A tcode

Tags: abap, badi

I am working on a requirement to update `MKPF-BKTXT` during save in `MB1A` tcode. I found `MB_DOCUMENT_BADI`, but the methods of the BADI only allows importing parameters and does not allow changing `MKPF`.

Has anyone in the community worked on similar? How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use BTE event 00001120 to do that and substitute BKTXT. Here is the detailed guide:

https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/ERPFI/Example+for+BTE+00001120

Just create Product, register your custom FM as process module and code your substitution.